# Mapping XML/JSON to relational table records and vice versa

Tags: json, xml, mapping, dsl

We have a requirement where we need to design a **generic** way of mapping various API responses (XML & JSON) to relational tables for data loading. This mapping needs to support other direction too i.e. relational table data needs to be parsed to compose an API request body sent to various API providers to update their systems data. These requirements are mainly to build a **generic API integration platform**. This platform allows the user to configure any enterprise system API calls and map them to our application data (relational) model and vice versa.

Below is an example of how relational table records need to be translated into the API request body to update other systems data

Denormalized table

```
Name        Transaction Details
Customer 1  Transaction 1
Customer 1  Transaction 2
Customer 1  Transaction 3
Customer 1  Transaction 4
```

Here's how the XML should look like

```
<Customer>          
    <Name>Customer 1</Name>
    <Transaction>       
        Transaction 1 details…  
    </Transaction>      
    <Transaction>       
        Transaction 2 details…  
    </Transaction>      
    <Transaction>       
        Transaction 3 details…  
    </Transaction>      
    <Transaction>       
        Transaction 4 details…  
    </Transaction>      
</Customer>
```

What are some of the suggestions to design and implement this mapping problem? Are there any DSL's (domain specific languages) created for such use cases?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider [graphql](http://graphql.org/learn/), and graphql/sql integrations,
such as https://github.com/rexxars/sql-to-graphql

Comment: How do you visualize graphql to be used for this problem? Note that we would not have a schema upfront since the user can configure any external system API calls based on the integration needs. I have edited the question to add more details. From the brief understanding I have for graphql, it requires a schema (types & fields) to be defined upfront.

Answer (score 0):

Symphonia Mapping Language (SML) comes packaged with [Orion's Rhapsody](https://orionhealth.com/us/) integration engine.  very adept at mapping XML or JSON to a relational data model, and Rhapsody and most other integration engines come with hooks to many flavors of databases.  Rhapsody is geared toward HL7 data and Healthcare implementations historically, but they are also handy for web services in general.  I am certain there are some free, or cheaper flavors of mapping, but for enterprise wide API stuff, these engines cannot be beat.

Comment: Looks like SML is a DSL(grammar) that for mapping different formats. Though I didn't specifically find RDBMS support but I assume it supports that too. Looks like this mapping language comes with Rhapsody. Any other open source DSL's that you know off for this problem domain?